# Can I Add an Audio File by Randomly Selecting the .mp3 File? FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently adding audio to video files with the below code where I occasionally swap out the specific audio file. Is there a way to randomly select and use an mp3 instead? I also need to retain the ability to control the volume of the added audio as I'm doing now. Is this possible? Ideally I'd like to do this in batch form as well for an entire folder of mp4s. I'm on Windows using CMD

```
ffmpeg -i audiofile.mp3 -i videofile.mp4 -filter_complex amix=normalize=0:weights="0.02 1" outputvideo.mp4
```

Comment: You have a folder with mp4 videos and another folder with mp3 audio files and you want to randomly and an audio for each video?

Comment: @RicardoBohner, that's correct. I have several videos to which I'd like to add 1 of 4 randomly selected audio files to

Comment: Do you mean substitute the original audio, or adding an extra audio to the video? Where should the modified videos be saved same folder as original with slightly other name?

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get it now. amix mixes the original audio with the mp3...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, you just have to change the locations of VideoFolder and AudioFolder variables acording to your folders:

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "VideoFolder=C:\Users\Ricardo\Videos"
set "AudioFolder=C:\Users\Ricardo\Music\The Official UK Top 100 (09-11-2023)"

IF NOT EXIST "%VideoFolder%\" exit
IF NOT EXIST "%AudioFolder%\" exit

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%AudioFolder%\*.mp3"') do (
                                                             set /a MaxAudioFiles+=1
                                                             set "Audio[!MaxAudioFiles!]=%%a"
                                                            )

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%VideoFolder%\*.mp4" "%VideoFolder%\*.mkv"') do Call :Mix "%%~a"
exit

:Mix
set /a RandomFile=%random% * (%MaxAudioFiles% - 1 + 1) /32768 + 1 
ffmpeg -i "%VideoFolder%\%~1" -i "%AudioFolder%\!Audio[%RandomFile%]!" -map_metadata -1 -filter_complex "amix=normalize=0:weights='0.02 1'" -y "%VideoFolder%\%~n1_mod%~x1"
goto :EOF
```